# Collapsing stone when there is no stone?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've recently undertaken some surface mining in DF, and I've having more collapses (and dead dwarves) than I ever did underground.

I have a ridge like

```
    ------
    xxxxxx
---------------
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

which I designate for digging like so

```
    ------
    dddddd
---------------
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Somehow I'm still getting a huge collapse which is killing my miners.  Is the "layer" dropping on my dwarves?

---

**Legend:**

- `x`: stone of some sort
- `-`: the layer
- `d`: designated for digging
- : open space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. Soil is just as deadly as stone when it comes to cave ins.

Rather than dig the ridge out from under it, go up one z-level and tell your dwarves to channel instead. They'll clear the same area, but as channeling also removes the soil floor tiles, it won't result in any cave-ins. (Though you may need to clear some trees, biome depending)

A safer alternative is to turn the hill into Upward Ramps (with **R** or **r**, I think?) and then remove the ramps with **z**. A two-step process, but no cave-ins, and no falling dwarves (even 1 z-level falls *occasionally* cause injuries).

Comment: I'm not sure it makes you wrong, but there was no "soil" present.  By "layer" I'm referring to the floor equivalent top of the ridge.

Comment: @C.Ross I was under the impression from "surface" mining, that you were not mining stone. You're right about the "layer" falling and killing them, which may or may not have been a soil floor. (But was definitely floor of some type!)

Comment: I'm strip mining, all that exposed hematite, coal, etc.

Comment: @C. Ross -- Noted! Still, gotta watch out for those ceilings! Channel down will net you those exposed minerals just the same.

Comment: I favor upward ramps, if all I have to worry about is a thin ceiling.

Comment: @Brilliand Yes, I came to that same conclusion sometime over the past four years. ;)

Comment: Removing the up-ramps isn't usually needed - most of the ramps will disappear on their own during the mining, and those that don't won't interfere with anything else you want to do with the land (such as strip-mining the next level down).

Comment: @Brilliand You may be underestimating the extent of my OCD. ;)